# How to add 3rd party application into Zend Framework 2 MVC (Apache)?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

Okay, so I'm using the Zend 2 Framework and I followed the basic Zend MVC style. But lets say I want to add site.com/blog (and blog being a 3rd party application). So how do I got about adding this? How do I tell the framework to ignore /blog? Would this just be a .htaccess change? (I'm using Apache)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^blog.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will detect that /blog/ is a real directory and it will be accessed just fine.
You can then have an htaccess file in the blog folder to do what ever rewrite you need there and that will override the base htaccess when accessing the blog directory

Comment: So currently (my .htaccess) it's sending almost everything to the Zend Framework right? I know for sure I have to have all host.com/bla/bla go to the framework, otherwise it won't be able to route it. I just need to say if the directory is /blog/ do nothing

Comment: @Josh - `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` does that already.  It adds a condition for the following RewriteRule that says "Only if the REQUEST_FILENAME is not a directory (!-d).  If it *is* a directory (like /public/blog), then apache should try to load whatever the DirectoryIndex is (usually /public/blog/index.php), and also process any additional directives in blog/.htaccess.

Comment: @Andrew - my only problem is that it currently says RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d, if I change that, will the apllicatoin stop working?

Comment: @Andrew - Okay, so I just stuck it on my server at http://test.spamus.us/ and it appears to be working correctly. but if I got to http://test.spamus.us/blog/asdf/ I go to the Zend framework 404 page.. Why? (note the only thing in /blog/ is a index.php) ... all I'm saying is anything in /blog/* should be going to /blog/index.php not /index.php

Comment: You'll essentially need the same rewrite rules for your `/blog` folder.

Comment: @Sam I tried that, it did not work. Sam, do you know of a way to just leave the .htaccess as is EXPECT tell it to not redirect the /blog/ folder? Post as an answer please.

Comment: Sadly my Server knowledge is too limited, but since this is a server related issue you may get higher quality answers on serverfault.com (stackexchang network, too)

Comment: You could put that same htaccess in the blog folder and then that will override the ZF htaccess. that should solve your issue, although depending on your blog that may use it's own rewrites.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've hit the nail on the head.  ZF2 will only interpret its routes after the webserver does its magic - so it isn't really a factor (and shouldn't be!).  For efficiency's sake, I would strongly recommend identifying the location of your blog as a separate location entity in your webserver config (so this never hits ZF2's shores).  Nginx does this really gracefully, here's a sample config:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

All kinds of good things happen, you can keep your wordpress separate from your ZF2 (in every respect), and there's no performance impact.  I haven't danced with Apache in awhile, but I'm certain there's an equivalent structure.  Sides, go NGINX ;)

Good luck!